# Postgres: abort transaction if SELECT returns any elements

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm writing a transaction that has a strict precondition. I would like to check that precondition at the start of the transaction, and abort if it doesn't hold. Pseudocode:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM widget WHERE widget.status = 'bad') > 0 THEN ABORT;
...
COMMIT;
END TRANSACTION;
```

Is this doable in Postgres?

Comment: No. SQL does not have 'IF/THEN'. FYI, `COMMIT` and `END TRANSACTION` are the same. Also `START TRANSACTION` can be shortened to `BEGIN`.

Answer (score -1):

`ABORT` rollsback the transaction. IF you dont want to continue to the procedure, you also need to call `RETURN`